# How to change tab size on GitHub?

Tags: tabs, github, tab-size

When I view files on GitHub, tabs appear as 8 spaces.

Example:

[image: example]

Is that possible to change this configuration to 2 or 4 spaces?

Comment: You can also check out answers provided in the GitHub issue [#170 `pre { tab-size: 4 }`](https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/170)

Comment: I think you should change the accepted answer to the one by @rofrol about using the `.editorconfig`, I think his answer includes current best methods for both setting the configuration in a way that other people will see the code as you intended it to be seen, and altering how other people's code looks when you are reading it.

Comment: @f1lt3r I disagree. If people really want to view my code with 8 spaces more power to them. I don't want to restrict them that way just so I can view it with 4 spaces on github for myself. If the answer is going to change, it should be mortenpi's answer

Comment: @Assimilater - rofrol's answer wouldn't restrict anyone from viewing whatever width they want. Agree that mortenpi's answer is good though pretty frustrating to have to add the param for every file you look at.

Comment: Can anyone explain the logic behind using 8 spaces as a default? I can't imagine any scenario where 8 spaces would look anything other than ridiculous - yet it's the default on github? What gives?

Comment: Eight space tabs was the Unix default many moons ago.  There's probably a ton of old C on GitHub that assumes it.

Comment: Indent size can be different then tab size. Most editors can still offer an indent size of 4, with a tab size of 8.  See this post: https://terminatorul.wixsite.com/blog/post/tabs-and-tab-size

Comment: Sept. 2021: you now have an official GitHub profile setting, which will apply to all GitHub pages. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69271299/6309).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### Update

**Yes**. As stated by mortenpi, this can be done by through an additional query parameter. See [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23522945/673852) for more details.

### Original answer

> Is that possible to change this configuration to 2 or 4 spaces?

No. It's only available as part of the editing feature through the [Ace](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace) editor and the change is not persisted.

This [blog post](https://github.com/blog/905-edit-like-an-ace) gives some more information about the embedded IDE.

However, provided you know the url of the blob (file) you're willing to review, you can switch to the edit mode easily by changing the **blob** segment with an **edit** segment and use the dropdown to select your prefered tab size.

[image: tabSize]

- Standard view: https://github.com/moroshko/mmSelect/blob/master/mm_select.js
- Ace view: https://github.com/moroshko/mmSelect/edit/master/mm_select.js

Comment: Great idea, but the problem is once you go into EDIT mode, you also FORK the said archive.  Might get a bit excessive after 50 or so view-only-edits ;)

Comment: Agreed. But that might be a good incentive to start *contributing* ;)

Comment: As @chrisdembia mentioned, this is no longer correct; github allows you to change tab size by passing the value as a query param (e.g., `?ts=4`)

Comment: Is there a way for the community to override the selected answer?

Comment: @chrisdembia Thanks for the reminders ;) Updated the answer to point to morenti's one.

Answer (score 414):

You can append `?ts=2` or `?ts=4` to the URL to change the tab-size.

Example: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/main/src/core.js?ts=2

It seems that the value can be anything from 1 to 12. It does not work on Gists or raw file views though.

Source: [GitHub Cheat Sheet](https://github.com/tiimgreen/github-cheat-sheet#adjust-tab-space)

Comment: It's good that this is possible, but it would be nice if there was an easy way to choose the tab width rather than having to remember the URL parameter.

Comment: It would also be nice if github let you save that as a preference so you wouldn't need to keep putting it back in the URL.

Comment: This seems to be no longer working. When viewing the example given above (https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js?ts=2) the tab size displays as 8, not 2.

Comment: @PhilDennis Works for me with Chrome (on Linux).

Comment: @NikolaMihajlović What do you mean by "in commits"? It appears to be working in the commit view (https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/1ea092a54b00aa4d902f4e22ada3854d195d4a18?ts=12) on Chrome/Linux.

Comment: @mortenpi Super weird, it seems it is selective about extensions e.g. doesn't work for json: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/6acf4a79467a5aea5bc1eb7d552d72366718635d#diff-df39304d828831c44a2b9f38cd45289c?ts=2

Comment: @NikolaMihajlović It's a bit subtle, but the ts argument needs to be before the # fragment in the URL. E.g. https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/6acf4a79467a5aea5bc1eb7d552d72366718635d?ts=4#diff-df39304d828831c44a2b9f38cd45289c

Comment: nice solution. sadly doesn't work on diffs in PR's.

Comment: in firefox you can use trumpio's addon _request control_ for creating rules. i apply the `ts` query parameter to every request to *.github.com.

Comment: @bbjay it does work for diffs in pull requests now.

Comment: @T3rm1 , the normal commit view or Files changed view in PRs seems not to handle `?ts=4` so far.  What is the trick?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore in 2021. GitHub automatically removes this from the URL. The example URL you gave ends up displaying 8-wide tabs.

Comment: You can now set tab width in github.com/settings/appearance (see VonC's answer below).

Comment: It's weird that this tops out at 12 spaces. I really want 24 spaces for viewing assembly listings in wide column format.

The `?ts=` query param changes the `data-tab-size="12"` HTML attribute on the table, which in turn changes the `tab-size` css value. The `data-tab-size` attribute only accepts the values 1-12. However, you can set the `tab-size` css value to anything and it works fine. For some reason there an indirect lookup between the data tribute and the actual CSS value that only respects tab spacing 1-12 and it's an annoying restriction.

Answer (score 338):

### Set default displayed tab size for your repository

> When you have a [.editorconfig](http://editorconfig.org/) in your repository it will respect it
>   when viewing code on GitHub.
>
> indent_style = tab and indent_size = 4 shows tabs with 4 columns
>   instead of 8
>   https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/170#issuecomment-150489692

[Example .editorconfig](https://github.com/rofrol/react-starter-kit/blob/master/.editorconfig) for multiple extensions which works in JetBrains' products:

```
root = true

[*]
end_of_line = lf
insert_final_newline = true

# Matches multiple files with brace expansion notation
[*.{js,jsx,html,sass}]
charset = utf-8
indent_style = tab
indent_size = 4
trim_trailing_whitespace = true

[*.md]
trim_trailing_whitespace = false
```

### Change how you see tabs on other repositories

Install [Stylus](https://add0n.com/stylus.html) in your browser, than install [GitHub: better-sized tabs in code](https://userstyles.org/styles/70979/github-better-sized-tabs-in-code).

There are also Google Chrome extensions:

- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/github-tab-sizer/djpnapkcpjomnkfekaedkigfomiedpjf
- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/github-tab-size/ofjbgncegkdemndciafljngjbdpfmbkn/related

Comment: It seems that github does not respect the editorconfig file for files with no names (.gitconfig, etc). Any idea why or is it a bug? Ex https://github.com/rmandvikar/git-setup/blob/tabs/.gitconfig

Comment: dotfiles don't seem to be respected with the `[*]` (on github). I had to add another entry with `[.*]`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer by far! I'm amazed that Github actually does follow editor config rules.

Comment: It's not respected in commits :-(

Comment: It fixes the size of a tab in your editor too, though, which kind of defeats the whole purpose of tabs.

Comment: Has this feature been removed from github? Some of my previously correct repo's seem to be reset to 8 spaces.

Comment: @Redsandro Can you make a testing repo?

Comment: @rofrol I think I was mistaken. The tab size works correctly in code and diffs, but not in `README.md` code snippets. This is a new observation; I don't know if `README.md` code snippets ever did tab sizes other than 8 spaces.

Comment: Unfortunately this only works on tab spacing from [1..12] which appears to be a fundamental limitation of the way that it's implemented on the page.

Answer (score 103):

[Since Sept. 2021](https://twitter.com/github/status/1440326215391350802), you can set the tab size directly in your GitHub settings: [`github.com/settings/appearance`](https://github.com/settings/appearance).

Announced in [Changelog "Tab size rendering preference"](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-09-21-tab-size-rendering-preference/).

- No more [`.editorconfig`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66611495/6309)
- No more [`?ts=2` added to the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23522945/6309)

Just:

[image: setting]

Note: you cannot enter "3" for instance. You would get:

> Tab size rendering preference could not be saved:
> Validation failed:
> Tab size is not included in the list

Comment: This answer should be higher up; it's unfortunate that the outdated answers have more votes. I initially saw the top two answers (by votes), thought that it wasn't possible as a user-specific setting and gave up. Then I stumbled across this setting by accident in the UI.

Comment: This doesn't replace .editorconfig. Different file formats need different indentation. That's kinda the point.

Comment: @Ryan I agree. This is not a complete solution

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything, is it session based? Edit: oh, it works on the editor view, I was expecting it to work in the code examples on a readme.

Answer (score 72):

It actually is possible to do it, with a browser extension. Install [Stylish](http://userstyles.org/) (in [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) or [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe)), then install this user style: “[GitHub: better-sized tabs in code](http://userstyles.org/styles/70979/github-better-sized-tabs-in-code)”.

It might not work for some languages. For example, I was viewing a JavaScript file and I did not notice any changes. So I deleted the style the author had and put the following lines into it:

```css
.tab-size {
  -webkit-tab-size: 4 !important;
     -moz-tab-size: 4 !important;
       -o-tab-size: 4 !important;
          tab-size: 4 !important;
}
```

And it worked on Chrome ([screenshot](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-STXLcJ_FMRV3JVM1dCTUhRdm8/edit?ups=drive_web_)).

As you can see from the screenshot, I also enabled widescreen mode and changed the color scheme to Solarized. So I have three user styles running on GitHub pages via the [Stylish extension for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe). I hope this helps someone.

Comment: I wrote [that user style](http://userstyles.org/styles/70979/github-better-sized-tabs-in-code). I’m glad you found it useful. I’ve fixed it and tested it in Chrome, and it now works without your modification.

Comment: You might also like my user style “[All code has tab size 4](http://userstyles.org/styles/89425/all-code-has-tab-size-4)”, which changes the tab size of `<code>` elements on all websites.

Comment: Hey Rory! Thank you for that style. I'll check out the other one as well. Only I like my tab to be size 2 so I think I'll thinker it a bit :P

Comment: Great tool. While I normally like a 2 space tab size, I noticed that setting it to two spaces hid some "white space anomalies" (lines with incorrect indentation) so I compromised and set stylish to 4.

Comment: Github replaces every `\t` with 8 `&nbsp;`. Merde.

Comment: Yep They did not do that before and I have no idea why they do that now :(

I guess a solution can be someone writing a script that replaces say... 4 consecutive &nbsp; with two or whatever. But that has to be a "userscript" I think.

Comment: Maybe a browser extension that would use @mortenpi's solution to append the official supported URL argument to GitHub URLs would do the trick?

Comment: @aledujke: Something like this: https://github.com/NV/tab_character_size Haven't tested as the site (userscripts.org) currently seems to be down.

Comment: Our [GitHub Dark](https://userstyles.org/styles/37035/github-dark) Stylish userstyle allows you to set the tab size. And it is being actively maintained.

Comment: This plugin definitely works but you need to tweak the selectors. A user helpfully provided a version in a [discussion post](https://forum.userstyles.org/discussion/46153/x) that works fine for me at time of writing.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane The extension does not work on diff. Someone proposed a fix a while ago already. Could you apply it?

Comment: @Ten I just updated the extension so it works in diffs too. Thanks for letting me know about the bug.

Comment: If you want it affect code examples on README files: `pre { tab-size: 2 !important }`

Answer (score 10):

If the project is yours, create a file in the project root named “.editorconfig” and give it the following contents.

```
[*]
indent_style = tab
indent_size = 4
```

This will cause GitHub to render tabs 4-wide within the project.

This is an [EditorConfig](https://editorconfig.org) file, which is formally specified, supported by many editors, and also supports more extensive editor configuration, like specifying that all .html files are UTF-8 encoded.

If the project isn’t yours, consider opening an issue requesting the author specify the indent style they intended.

Comment: `tab_width = 4` is more correct for specifying the rendering width of tabs, than `indent_size = 4` which specifies the default indentation width in an editor.

Comment: @Ryan I agree, but I’d note that setting `indent_size` is what you want if 1 indent = 1 tab: `tab_width` defaults to `indent_size`, and you’d only want to break that link if you want e.g. 1 indent = 2 tabs, or to indent using spaces and use tabs elsewhere.

Comment: Ahh, right! That's good to know.

Answer (score 0):

If you're into UserScripts, this did it for me:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         GitHub Tabs
// @namespace    http://foldoc.org/
// @version      1
// @description  Set sensible tabs on GitHub
// @author       Denis Howe
// @match        https://github.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

document.querySelectorAll('table').forEach(t => { t.dataset.tabSize = 2 });
```

Comment: I would have preferred this alternative but this seems to work more or less randomly: if the data was not loaded before the userscript runs (e.g. file listing then click to open the file), it doesn't work.

Comment: Good job, however, does not work for code blocks in the comment box.

Answer (score -4):

I did that for fixing them  http://valjok.blogspot.com/2014/07/indentation-correction-for-exposing.html.

Another option is when [embedding your gist](http://excelramblings.blogspot.com/2012/08/how-to-embed-gist-code-samples-in.html), replace all tabs with required number of spaces

```
<div id="willReplaceTabs">
 <script src="https://gist.github.com/valtih1978/99d8b320e59fcde634ad/cf1b512b79ca4182f619ed939755826c7f403c6f.js"></script>

 <script language="javascript">
  var spaces = "  "
  willReplaceTabs.innerHTML = willReplaceTabs.innerHTML.replace(/\t/g, spaces)
 </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score -8):

If it's an option for the project you're working on, changing your editor to treat tabs as spaces will fix the problem.

So, for example, in Visual Studio Code, the config looks like this:

```
{
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
    "editor.insertSpaces": true
}
```

In Sublime it's:

```
{
    "tab_size": 2,
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true
}
```

Until recently I insisted on non-spaced tabs. After switching, it fixed the Github rendering weirdness, and I haven't noticed any significant downsides in my workflow.

Answer (score -36):

The best solution is, if possible, to convince maintainers of the source code you're looking at to replace all the tabs by the correct number of spaces.

Using tabs is problematic in code today given that you're often seeing it on the web, where the decision of "how many spaces per tab" depends on where it's being displayed.

Comment: GitHub has a whitespace querystring var you can pass like `?w=1`. It'd be nice if they had a `?t=4' for 4 spaces or if you could somehow configure your project and it'd just pick it up, via Editor Config or something else.

Comment: This is the correct answer and does not deserve to be downvoted.  There's far too much software out there that doesn't let you change the tab width for "tabs are configurable" to be anything other than wishful thinking.  And if you ever indent anything a distance that *isn't* a multiple of your preferred tab width, you now have a mixture of tabs and spaces and adjusting the tab size doesn't even work anymore.

Comment: Read the Wikipedia article about where the 8-space tab comes from. “A common horizontal tab size of eight characters evolved, despite five characters being half an inch and the typical paragraph indentation of the time, because as a power of two it was easier to calculate in binary for the limited digital electronics available.” Your answer uses circular reasoning (i.e. the standard is eight characters because that’s the standard) to shut the door on the question. The asker is not satisfied with this standard and has little reason to be.

Comment: @mrjedmao It does, you can do `?ts=4`.

Comment: @Ben thanks. I probably figured that out right after I posed this comment, because I've known about `?ts=4` for a while now and sindresorhus created a Chrome plugin for that, so bonus there!

Comment: I prefer tab over space, because it speeds up my editing between 4 and 8 times when I move my cursor across a whitespace.

Comment: It should be noted that irregardless of whitespace preferences, there are times you are forced to use tabs such as Makefiles.  Been dealing with how our Makefiles look horrible on GitHub by default since we use 4 space wide tabs.

Comment: "nobody can tell other developers how they should format their code. Nobody." Except the person who's paying the developer, hmm?  "it speeds up my editing between 4 and 8 times when I move my cursor across a whitespace." Why do you do that to yourself, when all editors have a move-by-word/field/line feature?

Comment: "Except the person who's paying the developer, hmm?" Did your brain's IDE use its move-by-line feature to skip the following sentence? I explicitly stated that a project's enforced conventions take precedence over individual preferences. || "Why do you do that to yourself, when all editors have a move-by-word/field/line feature?" Yes, you're implying it's easier to use the feature of an editor to navigate code than to simply hit one key to traverse an entire column. Furthermore, not all editors have said features, and some even work differently. Stop thinking the whole world uses Sublime.

Comment: Sir, you have the correct answer. Looks like you got hated on pretty badly here!

Comment: If I quickly want to view a file in the browser that was intended to be viewed with a specific width of tabs (for alignment purposes), I'm not going to wait for months or potentially years for someone to change it.

Comment: Spaces or tabs is a whole different argument that you've successfully trolled. But your "answer" does not answer the question in any way.

Comment: This “solution” sounds like communism. “Just do the same because your opinion doesn’t matter.”