# Prevent 2 space tabs from switching to 4 space tabs when I push to github

Tags: vim, github

In VIM I've, all my tabs are 2 spaces. But when I push to github, they get converted to 4 spaces. Can anyone help me figure out how to prevent them from getting converted to 4 spaces?

My vimrc file:

```
call pathogen#infect()
call pathogen#runtime_append_all_bundles()

" search
set hlsearch                  " highlight the search
set incsearch                 " incremental search
set ignorecase                " search ignoring case
set showmatch                 " show matching bracket

" colors
set background=dark
let g:solarized_termcolors=8 " proper solarized coloring
colorscheme peachpuff

" syntax
syntax on
filetype on                   " Enable filetype detection
filetype plugin on            " Enable filetype-specific plugins
filetype indent on            " Enable filetype-specific indenting

set ruler                     " show the line number on the bar
set more                      " use more prompt
set autoread                  " watch for file changes
set number                    " line numbers
set hidden
set noautowrite               " don't write old file out when switching files
set lazyredraw                " don't redraw when don't have to
set showmode
set showcmd
set nocompatible              " vim, not vi
set autoindent smartindent    " auto/smart indent
set smarttab                  " tab and backspace are smart
set tabstop=2                 " 6 spaces
set shiftwidth=2
set scrolloff=5               " keep at least 5 lines above/below
set sidescrolloff=5           " keep at least 5 lines left/right
set history=200
set backspace=indent,eol,start
set linebreak
set cmdheight=2               " command line two lines high
set undolevels=1000           " 1000 undos
set updatecount=100           " switch every 100 chars
set complete=.,w,b,u,U,t,i,d  " do lots of scanning on tab completion
set ttyfast                   " we have a fast terminal
set noerrorbells              " No error bells please
set shell=bash
set fileformats=unix
set ff=unix
set wildmode=longest:full
set wildmenu                  " menu has tab completion
set laststatus=2
set diffopt=filler,iwhite     " ignore all whitespace and sync

" scss formatting
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.scss ""set ft=scss.css

" jade formatting
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.jade setlocal ft=jade noexpandtab
autocmd FileType jade :setlocal sw=2 ts=2 sts=2

autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree
autocmd VimEnter * wincmd p
autocmd Filetype javascript setlocal ts=2 sw=2 sts=0 noexpandtab
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard *representation* of a tab character is 8 spaces. In reality, the tab is a control character and as such doesn't have an associated glyphs or a set width. This allows most programs to offer a way to modify how it is *displayed* but no program ever change its width because it doesn't have one to start with: a tab is still a tab, no matter the value of `tabstop`.

Your Vim settings only alter how tabs are *displayed* in Vim: they have no bearings on how they are displayed outside of Vim.

You have two solutions:

- set GitHub and Vim to use the same tab width
- use spaces

---

Since we are at it…

```
set background=dark
let g:solarized_termcolors=8 " proper solarized coloring
colorscheme peachpuff
```

You can delete the solarized line if you don't use it and `set background` is useless because your colorscheme takes care of that.

```
set noautowrite
```

is also useless because `autowrite` is off by default.

And

```
call pathogen#runtime_append_all_bundles()
```

serves no purpose whatsoever.

Comment: `set background` is *not* useless. It is one of the solarized settings, similar to `g:solarized_*`. In fact, some colorschemes do check `&background` before setting `Normal` highlighting (which, according to the doc, will reset `&background`) and solarized is one of them.

Comment: Also note that `set noautowrite` may not be useless because `set autowrite` could be specified in `/etc/vimrc`/`/etc/vim/vimrc` or whatever is used by your linux distribution.

Comment: What *is* wrong in the settings is `set nocompatible`. According to the doc this resets `set hlsearch`, `set incsearch`, `set more`, `set ruler`, `set showcmd` and `set showmode` making all these definitions useless. @bob_cobb should have placed `set nocompatible` at the top of the vimrc.

Comment: Its position is also wrong because solarized colorscheme requires vim being in `nocompatible` mode (or, more specific, at least `cpoptions` setting that allows line continuation; maybe also some other options). Thus if OP has not already had vim running in `nocompatible` mode due to presence of the `vimrc` file (vim automatically sets `nocompatible` if it finds `.vimrc`) this vimrc would be failing.

Comment: @ZyX, he is not using solarized so any setting related to that colorscheme is redundant and setting `background` to `dark` just before the chosen colorscheme sets it to `light` doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @ZyX, and `nocompatible` is almost totally useless as it is set automatically if a `~/.vimrc` is found. At this point of the initialization, all the options are simply set accordingly whether/wherever you have `set nocompatible` in your `~/.vimrc`. The only use of that line in one's `vimrc` is for `$ vim -u /pat/to/my/vimrc`.

Comment: If you know you may want to source vimrc with `-u` it is better to set it rather then not. It must be the first one in any case though, not like here: all options mentioned in `:h 'compatible'` are always reset on `set *compatible`, no matter whether or not `&compatible` value changed. Even Gentoo maintainers agree on this, setting `nocompatible` in `/etc/vim/vimrc` and so does `vimrc_example.vim` distributed with vim. I have not noticed that OP does not use `solarized` though.

Comment: Yes for the scnario and yes for that line at the top of the vimrc.

Comment: Yeah, what ZyX said. I need `call pathogen#runtime_append_all_bundles()` in order to use NerdTree also.

Comment: ZyX said many things and that function is deprecated: it is a proxy for incubate() and incubate() is already called by infect().

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reading this on how to change tabsize for [Github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833953/how-to-change-tab-size-on-github)

There appears to be a browser extension called Stylish that changes tabs in Github by downloading the style ["Better sized tabs in code"](http://userstyles.org/styles/70979/github-better-sized-tabs-in-code)

Download the browser extension and use the style and change the tab spacing to two space tabs.

Hope this helped!