# Tab-size in files on Git

Tags: github, sublimetext3

In my sublime by defoult I have Tab-size:2, and all code looks good, but when I push it to the repo - my code became unreal for read, it has huge indents.

Is this normal, or I something missed?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change tab size on GitHub?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833953/how-to-change-tab-size-on-github)

Comment: That's because tab size is, by design, user-configurable. Tabs may look like two spaces in your editor, but they may look like 16 spaces in mine. Looking like 8 spaces is a common default, which looks to be what GitHub is using.

Comment: If you always want your indent to be 2 space everywhere, use space for tabs instead of tabs. You can configure that in Sublime Text. Use this setting: `"translate_tabs_to_spaces": true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to avoid this using spaces instead of tabs. Set `translate_tabs_to_spaces` to true. See [Indentation Settings](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/indentation.html) for details.