# How to change tab size in GitHub desktop app?

Tags: github, tabs, settings, github-for-windows, github-for-mac

I'm working on a project that uses tabs incorrectly, and therefore doesn't like that the GitHub desktop app shows them as being 4 spaces wide in the diff.

This is not nice as it's hard to read the diff inside the app because the code shows up as not being properly indented.

Is there a setting that allows to customize the tab size?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change tab size on GitHub?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833953/how-to-change-tab-size-on-github)

Comment: oh, I stopped reading at GitHub, my bad!

Answer (score 2):

2021: There is at least a [setting on github.com](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69271299/6309).

2015: I just checked with the latest version of GitHub for Windows (2.14.7), and this option doesn't seem to be available.

[image: G4W]

Comment: Still not seeing this option today on github-for-Mac v 3.1.2... :,(

Comment: @kubicle True, this is still not directly visible in the GitHub Desktop application.

Answer (score 2):

One can edit the installed stylesheet for GitHub Desktop.

Add the following to `GitHub\ Desktop.app/Contents/Resources/app/renderer.css` on Mac:

```
* { tab-size: 4; }
```

This likely will be reset after an update, but I'll cross that bridge when it comes.

Comment: This is quite hacky but it works - also under Windows.
Under Windows I found renderer.css under
`%LOCALAPPDATA%\GitHubDesktop\app-3.3.6\resources\app`
so it's version specific.

Comment: it's `/var/lib/flatpak/app/io.github.shiftey.Desktop/current/active/files/github-desktop/resources/app/renderer.css` in Linux.