# Github changes indentation

Tags: ruby, github, sublimetext2

I've pushed my code in Ruby to remote Github repository. My code looks completely different now - in Sublime text it was perfectly fomatted, 2 spaces indentation as it should be in Ruby for every logical level. But on Github it's all over the place. What's the reason for it and what can I do to have my code exactly the same as locally?

Comment: mixed tabs and spaces? how is your sublime set up?

Comment: I used only spaces, no tabs

Comment: can you double-check your `translateTabsToSpaces` in Sublime, it should be set to true.

Comment: Windows, Linux, Mac? On Windows, when you install Git it defaults to switching line endings at a minimum. Don't know if it does any other weirdness.

Comment: thank you for your advice, I chose Preferences -> Settings - User and I placed "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true inside and saved it. Should it work now on Github after pushing it one more time?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/changing-spaces-tabs-sublime-text/

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu. I changed it, pushed again but still the same problem. My code looks totally different - if, end were on the same level, now it's in completely different place, while in Sublime it looks perfectly fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had this issue before, but, it isn't with GitHub, it is with your code. If you use a tab and tell Sublime show it as 2 spaces it is still passing `\t` and not `\s\s` in the code.

The real solution is to us spaces `\s` instead of tabs `\t`, you can easily change a tab to 2 spaces in Sublime, Vim, Text-mate or whatever you want to use. Then the formatting will look the same for everyone and on all platforms.

The Sublime docs for tabs to spaces.
https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/indentation.html

Also check out this question for more about tabs in Github.
[How to change tab size on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833953/how-to-change-tab-size-on-github)

Comment: Thank you, I'll try, but I've used only spaces - never hit a "tab" button in my code