# Change Github online editor tab indent size

Tags: github, editor

I am writing blog using Jekyll on github page.

Instead of using offline editors, I use github online editor which supports  markdown very well.

But I when I edit posts, github editor set the default indent size to 8. I tried to change it to 4, but after I save it and reedit this post, github editor reset the indent size to 8.

I am wondering why this happens. How can I set the default indent size to 4 for every file?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: **See Also**: [How to change tab size on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8833953/1366033)

Comment: Sept. 2021: you now have an official [GitHub setting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69271299/6309)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a permanent setting. You can change it for the edit mode with the dropdown you mention and for blob mode by appending `?ts=4` to the URL on a per-file basis.

If you're using chrome, you could use [Sindre Sorhus' tab-size-on-github](https://github.com/sindresorhus/tab-size-on-github) extension that does exactly what you want: Force all tabs to represent 4 spaces always.

Comment: Do you mean appending ?ts=4 to the URL like this? https://github.com/shic/blog/edit/gh-pages/_posts/2016-03-29-Javascript-Basic.markdown?ts=4
This not works for me.
Unfortunately, also the Chrome extension not works. Maybe github changed their rules. Thanks for the response any way.

Comment: The parameter only works in the **view** mode (with `blob` instead of `edit` in the URL). However, this does not work for your example because the setting is not picked up for code embedded in Markdown.