# How to set tab size in GitHub web interface

Tags: git, github, repository

So I recently created a GitHub account. Among other things a problem that I seem to have it `tabs`. When you are creating a new folder in repository, Github hasthe following options:

- Indent Mode

  - Spaces
  - Tabs
- Indent Size

  - 2
  - 4
  - 8
- Line Wrap mode

  - No wrap
  - Soft wrap

The problem I seem to be having is that when I set the following values:

- indent mode to `tabs`
- indent size to `4`

When I save that file it is automatically set to tabs and 8

What is going on here?

Why is indent size getting set to 8 even when I specifically set it to 4?

Comment: How are you verifying that the indent size is set to 8 instead of 4?

Comment: @Flimzy : After saving when I go back to check the tab size is 8, also when I go to edit mode again tab size is 8

Comment: @MuhammadSalman Can you approve the answer below if it serves your purpose?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change tab size on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833953/how-to-change-tab-size-on-github)

Comment: Sept. 2021: you now have a [GitHub setting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69271299/6309)!

Answer (score 4):

The default tab size in GitHub is set to  8.

You can achieve indentation by using selecting indent mode as **spaces** and setting it to 4 or whatever you want.

To check the file on GitHub with different indentation you can  append `?ts=2` or `?ts=4` to the URL to change the tab-size.