# Indentation is corrupted when I post a file to GitHub, when it looks OK in Notepad++ and VS Code

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, notepad++

I have some weird issue: It's not very important, but I want my code to look nice on GitHub.

I've implemented MergeSort in AEC, and I posted it to GitHub, you can see it [here](https://github.com/FlatAssembler/ArithmeticExpressionCompiler/blob/master/MergeSort/msort.aec).
However, the indentation doesn't look the same as it does in Notepad++ or VS Code, here is how the lines 101-107 look if I open that file in Notepad++:

[image: How it looks in Notepad++]

I don't expect syntax highlighting to work on GitHub, the syntax highlighting for AEC works in Notepad++ because I opened the Notepad++ [script](https://flatassembler.000webhostapp.com/Arth.xml) to highlight AEC code.
However, I would expect the indentation to look the same whether it's on GitHub or in a text editor.
So, why it doesn't?

Comment: I guess tab width are not the same.

Comment: In Notepad++, check Settings > Preferences > Language > Tab Settings. In VS Code, check Settings > "editor indentation". You probably have mismatched indentation settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does look the same with this URL: [`MergeSort/msort.aec?ts=4`](https://github.com/FlatAssembler/ArithmeticExpressionCompiler/blob/master/MergeSort/msort.aec?ts=4)

The tab width on GitHub is 8 by default, but you can [change it through a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23522945/6309).

There is no global preference though. You would need [a Userscript to make it (locally) persistent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57523286/6309).

Comment: Can I somehow force an editor to convert every tab to a certain number of spaces?

Comment: @FlatAssembler It depends on the editor. Here is an example for Notepad++: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7471232/6309. For VSCode: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29972553/6309

Comment: @FlatAssembler I have edited my previous comment to include VSCode.