# editorconfig not retaining formatting on Github Repo files

Tags: javascript, github, editorconfig

I don't get it, why isn't my code showing up in this format on github for my repo when I view the code on github?

**.editorconfig**

```
root = true

[*.js]
indent_style = tab
indent_size = 2
```

Instead it's showing up like this:
[image]

Comment: This is very likely related to a change on GitHub, that there is now a user setting for tab indent: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833953/how-to-change-tab-size-on-github/69271299#69271299 and https://github.blog/changelog/2021-09-21-tab-size-rendering-preference/