# Github Code displaying wrong indentation issue

Tags: github

I realized that when I push my code to my GitHub repo, the indentation is being displayed as 8..? but In my VSCODE, I have set my indentation as 2.

Is there a permanent fix to this issue? I am aware that I can go into my code and press the pen icon and view my code in 2 spaces, 4 spaces or 8 spaces using the options but this doesn't change my code being displayed in 2 spaces permanently.

Below is the image comparison

[image: Github displaying wrong indentation]

[image: Indentation in my vscode]

Comment: I think this is a bug with GitHub itself it happed to me also. I recommend contacting GitHub on this Thanks...I thought it was a problem with my crappy pc but now I know that it is not only happening to me

Comment: use eslint and pretteier extension

Comment: howwould that exactly help..? I mean, I am using prettier on my vscode already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double-check first your GitHub account settings "Tab Size Preference" ([new since Sept. 2021](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833953/how-to-change-tab-size-on-github))

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4n7n.png]

Those should apply to *all* of your repositories.