# Problems with indentations on Github

Tags: github, indentation

I have some issues with my indentations on GitHub: It shows that I have an indent size of 8 on GitHub even after I changed it to indent size 2 and pushed it.

I have changed the settings on prettier so the code has a indent size 2, and look as it should in my VSCode, but when I commit it is still has a indent size 8.

Attached some photos below and a link to my repo: https://github.com/MT-dotse/project-mongo-api/blob/master/server.js

- Code on VSCode: [image: Code on VS code]
- Code on GitHub: [image: Code on GitHub]

Comment: Hi managed to solve the issue! I needed to uncheck the  "use tabs" , and change the tab width to 2 in the prettier extention.

Comment: Well done, good catch. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do see your code on GitHub with the expected tab size of 2, not 8.

But that is only because I have set my [GitHub account setting "Tab Size"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69271299/6309) to 2.
Which means any tab is displayed (in my GitHub session on a browser page) as 2 spaces, not 8.

---

As the [OP Madelene](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16651671/madelene) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70774875/problems-with-indentations-on-github?noredirect=1#comment125161561_70774875), as an alternative solution:

> I needed to uncheck the "`use tabs`", and change the tab width to 2 in the prettier extension.

Comment: Why do you need to change the tab width if tabs are no more used ??

Comment: @YvesDaoust On GitHub, this is just to make sure tabs are represented with the expected number of spaces. The OP went for an alternative solution.

Comment: MH, I don't get it. If there are no tabs in the original file, this is irrelevant.